# Setting up a server on the port 80 without a domain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I know how to setup a server on nginx with https with a domain. Now I only need to setup a server on the port 80 and without a domain name, only with an ip address and it should be visible in the internet.

How can I do that properly? Note that my internal built-in server runs on the port 2222. For now I have this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    access_log /var/log/my_website.log;
    error_log /var/log/my_website.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://localhost:2222;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:2222 ?????; # what should be here?
    }
}
```

Is there anything I should remove or add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)

```
A server name may be omitted in the replacement string:
     proxy_redirect http://localhost:8000/two/ /;
then the primary server’s name and port, if different from 80, will be inserted.
```

So I think just using `/` is enough

Answer (score 0):

`server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2222;
    }
}`

Comment: It looks like you may have the knowledge to provide good Answer here, but please consider reading [How do I write a good Answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help center and then revise the Answer. Your Commands/Code/Settings may technically be the solution but  some explanation and context is welcome. Thanks in advance.